# Discrepancy between simulation and theoretical

Tags: trigonometry

I've come up with a few equations for some angles of a quadrilateral given 4 sides $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, and one angle $\beta$. However, when I simulate it in a geometry tool, I'm getting quite different values. The diagram looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know if my equations below are indeed correct? I've already checked through them several times but I can't see where the mistake might be.

$\theta^\prime =\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin (\beta ) (a-b \cos (\beta ))}{b}\right)$

$\theta^{\prime\prime} = \cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{-c^2+d^2-g^2}{2 c g}\right)$

$\theta^{\prime\prime\prime} = \frac{\pi }{2}-\beta$

$g = b \csc (\beta ) \sqrt{\frac{\sin ^2(\beta ) (a-b \cos (\beta ))^2}{b^2}+1}$

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one:

$$\tan\theta'=\frac{a-b\cos\beta}{b\sin\beta}$$ so

$$\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a-b\cos\beta}{b\sin\beta}\right)$$

which makes the fourth one also wrong. The second and the third are OK.

If the segment between $\theta$ and $\theta'$ is $x$ then:

$x=b\sin\beta$ and $x=g\cos\theta'$ so $x=\frac{b}{\csc\beta}$ and

$$g=x\frac{1}{\cos\theta'}=\frac{b}{\csc\beta}\sqrt{\tan^2\theta'+1}$$

Then, you use your first identity to arrive to the correct formula.

Comment: Thanks! I actually left out a pair of brackets!